# Find a simple necessary and sufficient condition, which depends only on g

Tags: real-analysis

So I have this problem

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$f (x, y) = \cosh (g (x, y))$, where
$g \in  C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\cosh\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is known to be given by $\cosh(x)=\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)/2$

Assume that g is different from $0$ everywhere.

a) Let $(x_0, y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Find a simple necessary and
sufficient condition, that only
depends on $g$ (or its derivative)
at the point $(x_0, y_0)$, so that $(x_0, y_0)$ is
a critical point for $f$.

So I know that I need to use the chain rule and partially derive with respect to x and y. And then I have to look at the partially derivative when it's $0$.

But I can't seem to figure out how to derive, can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = sinh \left( g(x,y) \right) \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule is
$$
(h\circ g)'(x,y)=h'(g(x,y))\cdot g'(x,y).
$$
For $h=\cosh$, we have
$$
(\cosh\circ\ g)'(x,y)=\sinh(g(x,y))\cdot g'(x,y).
$$
Since $\sinh$ is bijective and $\sinh(0)=0$, we know $(x,y)$ is a critical point, if $g(x,y)=0$ or $g'(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Now, we have to do it once again. From
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\sinh(g(x,y))\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
$$
follows
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\sinh(g(x,y))\cdot\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}+\cosh(g(x,y))\cdot \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\sinh(g(x,y))\cdot\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y}+\cosh(g(x,y))\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
$$
If $g(x,y)=0$, the hessian is $\begin{pmatrix} \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)^2 & \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}&\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)^2\end{pmatrix}$, which is positive semi-definite.

Of course for $(x,y)$ with $g(x,y)=0$, we have a global minimum, since $\cosh(a)>1=\cosh(0)$ for all $a\neq 0$.

If $g'(x,y)=(0,0)$, the hessian is $$\sinh(g(x,y))\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y}&\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}\end{pmatrix},$$ which is almost the hessian of $g$, i.e. if $g$ has a critical point at $(x,y)$, then $f$ has a critical point at $(x,y)$ as well. This sounds reasonable, since $\cosh$ is monotonely increasing on the  interval $(0,\infty)$ and monotonely decreasing on the  interval $(-\infty,0)$ .